# How can I run sorting algorithms parallel?

Tags: node.js

I implemented 3 sorting algorithms, and I want to run them in parallel and have their `console.log` print as soon as it is finished. I tried using the `parallel` function using Async library (https://github.com/caolan/async) and it doesn't seem to be behave the way I would expect it to. I saw some topics about spawning child processes, but it always seems to wait for one sort to finish before executing the next one; It always prints in the order executed. I would think my faster sort would print before the slower ones regardless of execution order. Is it possible to achieve this type of behavior with node.js? If so, how? If not, why not?

Answer (score 0):

I really like this library: http://adambom.github.io/parallel.js/

You can use it like so (from the docs):

```
var slowSquare = function (n) { 
    var i = 0; 
    while (++i < n * n) {}
    return i; 
};

// Create a job
var p = new Parallel(100000);

// Spawn our slow function
p.spawn(slowSquare).then(yourCallback);
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorting is a synchronous operation.

Because `Node.js` is single-threaded there is no way to run several sorts in parallel withous spawning several [child processes](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html). Single `Node.js` process just can't run synchronous code in parallel.

The best thing you can do is to wrap each sorting algorithm into a meta-function which will spawn a child process and then will dispatch the actual sorting to it.

It you want to achieve parallelism in production then it's best to use something like [cluster](http://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html) to keep a set of workers instead of spawning a new one for each task.

There are some ready-to-use libraries with similar functionality. I just found one using google: [node-compute-cluster](https://github.com/lloyd/node-compute-cluster). **Connor Black** mentioned another on [in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19435727/how-can-i-run-sorting-algorithms-parallel/19435943#19435943).